# LeetCode 409. Longest Palindrome, why does my code not work?

Tags: java

I was practicing leetcode and I came across the problem of the longest palindrome, I made a solution but it wont completely work. I have been looking for similar codes with explanations on why they don't work, but have not been successful. Can someone explain why my code does not work even though it makes perfect sense to me? At some points the outputs are not correct.

```java
public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
    HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    if (s.length() <= 0)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
        }
        else
            map.put(c, 1);
    }
    for (int frequency : map.values()) {
        if (frequency % 2 == 0)
            count += frequency;
        else {
            if (frequency > odd)
                odd = frequency;
        }
    }
    return count + odd;
}
```

In my code I'm adding the frequencies of the characters in the string to a map. After that I go through the values in the map and add the even frequencies to a counter and only add the largest odd frequency to it.

This another example is of a code that does work:

```
public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int[] count = new int[128];
    int oddCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        count[s.charAt(i)]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        if (count[i] % 2 != 0) {
            oddCount++;
        }
    }
    if (oddCount == 0) {
        return s.length();
    }
    return s.length() - oddCount + 1;
}
```

I looked up for more solutions like the one I listed above but I don't want to copy and paste it and write it off as my own work, I want to understand why my code does not work, or how could I make it work! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: You can use all the even count letters and one less of the odd count letters, except 1 odd letter that may sit in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the reasoning of the line

```
if(frequency > odd) odd = frequency;
```

Typically here, when the frequency is an odd number, you want to use all except 1 of such character. There may be a few of them in the loop but eventually, you'd use only one of them when you do count + odd, at the end.

so change this to

```
for(int frequency : map.values()){
    if(frequency % 2 == 0){
        count += frequency;
    } else{
        //if(frequency > odd) odd = frequency;
        count += frequency -1;
        odd =1;
    }
}
```

The whole thing

```
public int longestPalindrome(String s) {
    HashMap<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    int count = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    if(s.length() == 0) return 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(map.containsKey(c)){
            map.put(c , map.get(c) + 1);
        }
        else map.put(c,1);
    }

    for(int frequency : map.values()){
        if(frequency % 2 == 0){
            count += frequency;
        } else{
            //if(frequency > odd) odd = frequency;
            count += frequency -1;
            odd =1;
        }
    }
    return count + odd;
  }
```

Comment: I thought that you could use only one odd frequency in the whole palindrome, it seems I was mistaken. So to see if I understood you, subtract 1 to the odd frequency in order to make it even and add it to the total, but then at the end, only add one to the count because that would be the odd character in the middle?

Comment: correct If feel fuzzy just debug or manually run through it on paper may help.